# How to put headers in axios all

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

Where to put the headers in axios all

```
axios.all([
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/mapbox'),
  axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/phantomjs')
])
.then(axios.spread((user1, user2) => {
  console.log('Date created: ', user1.data.created_at);
  console.log('Date created: ', user2.data.created_at);
}));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a specific axios instance that you could use.

```
import axios from 'axios';
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.github.com/users/';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
});

export default instance;
```

then import it and use it accordingly

```
import axios from '../my-axios-github-instance';

axios.all([
  axios.get('mapbox'),
  axios.get('phantomjs')
])
.then(axios.spread((user1, user2) => {
  console.log('Date created: ', user1.data.created_at);
  console.log('Date created: ', user2.data.created_at);
}));
```